# name 'linear_model' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel('C:\Data.xlsx')
#print (df.head())

x_train = df['Father'].values[0:15]
y_train = df['Son'].values[0:15]

x_test = df['Father'].values[15:]
#print (x_test)

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x_train, y_train)

-----------------------------------------

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
NameError: name 'linear_model' is not defined
```

Comment: You've imported `LinearRegression` so just use it.  You don't need to prepend it with `linear_model.` By the way, command-k will automatically indent your code in stack overflow once pasted and selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are importing modules like this:

```
import foo
```

you need to call the function like this:

```
foo.bar()
```

But when you are importing modules like this:

```
from foo import bar
```

you call functions like this:

```
bar()
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this to your Code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
```